# iOS: how to invite user to connect only if the user have such app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, backend

*Prolog*

I made an app which include function of data exchange. Data exchange work over Internet(including mobile Internet). I made this with Game Center multiplayer. But, Apple reject my app for this. Anyway, I want to make this function for release. I already find service that could help me with app backend, here it is if someone interested: [App Warp](http://appwarp.shephertz.com).

---

Now, my question: right now I encountered trouble of invites. When I use Game Center, it gives me already registered users and I can send them invites to connect for data exchange, user received push notification with invitation text and he could continue for data exchange, but if this user hadn't got the app, Game Center suggest him to buy/download the app.

This was a great feature, but right now I need to make such by myself. My app need to send push notifications to start data exchange (push notif. will provide some connection information), but if a user haven't my app he can't receive such push notification at all.

I thought to use `Address Book` for list of contacts but what to do next? Send them email to ask if they have such app or put this stuff on user shoulders? I'm a bit at an impasse.

Maybe there is such way to know if user already have such app or not? Or maybe social networks can help me somehow? I hope somebody know the answer. If you want to know additional information let me know and I answer you as soon as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as far as I know but look at this website http://www.mac4ever.com from a mobile device, if you dont have the app installed it prompts you to view it on the app store

So you could send an email which leeds the invitee to a webpage that implements this mechanism

From that web page you will need to invoke a custom URL that starts your app to complete the pairing with your friend (e.g. com.pleeq.anchor://pairuser?id=)

For creating a custom URL you can refer to this page: http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

On a side note, If apple forbids you to use game center for this purpose have you looked at using alternatives which may be less regarding? OpenFeint or other?